# Placa de Leds e Arduino

Tags: c, arduino, automatização

Boa noite,

Estou programando um arduino uno usando C. Estou usando um led RGB em três saídas PWM. Porém, surge agora a necessidade de ligar mais leds, cem leds ao mesmo tempo, porém além de não ter as portas necessárias preciso de uma solução para poder controlar os leds de forma individual.

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 2):

**Solução Parcial**:

Esta pergunta são na realidade duas: como ligar e como programar.
(Claro que é relevante saber quantas portas dispões...)

Vou falar apenas da ligação.

Os leds só acendem se a corrente passar no sentido certo. Portanto é possível colocar 2 leds entre cada par de portas (com sentidos opostos).

Se entre cada par de portas `(n*(n-1))/2` colocares 2 leds obtens 
um "**Charlieplexer**"

Se tiveres 11 portas (e bastante fio...), podes usar directamente o Arduino  em  "CarliePlexing" controlando 11*10 leds.

(As portas Arduino podem estar em estado "+" "-" "desligado").

Infelizmente não podemos ter os dois leds (p1=+,p2=-) e 
(p2=-,p1=+) ligados ao mesmo tempo. Porem se com o controlador comutarmos entre os dois com velocidade, veremos os dois ligados.

http://www.instructables.com/id/Controlling-20-Leds-from-5-Arduino-pins-using-Cha/step2/Charlieplexing-The-theory/

Se tiveres "poucas" portas poderás precisar de hardware adicional (multiplexers ou semelhantes)

**Update: Usando hardware externo**
(--> propurar arduino+multiplexer no tio google...)

Os multiplexer permitem "desmultiplicar" saidas/entradas.
Por exemplo um multiplexer/desmultiplexer de 16 vai precisar de 4 pinos para selecionar a saida pretendida e mais um para o sinal.

http://tronixstuff.com/2013/08/05/part-review-74hc4067-16-channel-analog-multiplexerdemultiplexer/

Os multiplexer podem ser ancadeados...

Por exemplo em: 
https://miulinglam.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/arduino-multiplexing-example-1/
encontras um arduino com encadeamento de 3 multiplexer de 8 canais.

Comment: OLá, não vejo problema nenhum em utilizar hardware adicional

Comment: @LucasTorres, vê o update...

Answer (score -1):

Me parece impossível controlar os 100 leds aos mesmo tempo sem hardware externo.

Você pode tentar algo do tipo:

Ligar um dos lados (catodo ou anodo) dos led nas entradas digitais. Ligar todos os outros lados (catodo se escolheu anodo antes) do led na mesma saída PWM. Assim você poderia fechar o circuito apenas do led que quer acender com uma determinada composição RGB baseada nos valores da porta PWM no momento que fechar o circuito. Se você fizer isso muito rapidamente talvez obtenha a sensação que todos os LED estão acessos.

Você precisaria de um clock para sincronizar...

Comment: Marcelo/Gabriel, na verdade eu não preciso acender todos ao mesmo tempo, e esse é o problema. Ora preciso acender o led 1 vermelho, led 2 apagado, led 3 azul.... Ora led 1 apagado, led2 apagado, led 3 amarelo...